# Как выбирать код в зависимости от браузера?

Tags: html, javascript

Код кнопки одной:

```
<a href='http://ingsh.ucoz.ru/recomended_browser.html' title="Рекомендуемый браузер" target="_blank"><img src='http://ingsh.ucoz.ru/recomended_browser.png'></a>
```

А как сделать так, чтобы: если кто-либо зашёл на сайт через браузер **Mozilla Firefox**, тут же менялась ссылка, описание и изображение. Вот такое чтобы стало:

```
<a href='http://ingsh.ucoz.ru/recomended_browser_completed.html' title="У Вас уже стоит браузер: Mozilla Firefox можете сюда не входить, разве что только обновить свою версию" target="_blank"><img src='http://ingsh.ucoz.ru/recomended_browser_completed.png'></a>
```

Comment: Чтобы код форматировался, нужно выделить его мышью и нажать 101010 или добавить четыре пробела перед каждой строкой.

Answer (score 2):

**Полностью переделан ответ:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hide-class{
            display: none;
    }
    </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://masterplay.ru/media/jquery-1.4.3.js"></script><!-- Обратите внимание на это подключение jquery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        if ($.browser.opera) {
            $(".our-a").addClass("hide-class");
            $("#a-in-opera").removeClass("hide-class");
        }
        else if ($.browser.mozilla) {
            $(".our-a").addClass("hide-class");
            $("#a-in-mozilla").removeClass("hide-class");
        }
        else{
            $(".our-a").addClass("hide-class");
            $("#a-in-other-browsers").removeClass("hide-class");
        }
    });
</script>
<title>тестовая страница</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="#" id="a-in-opera" class="our-a">some text - opera</a>
    <a href="#" id="a-in-mozilla" class="hide-class our-a">some text - mozilla</a>
    <a href="#" id="a-in-other-browsers" class="hide-class our-a">some text - other</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Извините за глупость и наглость, а можно пожалуйста поподробнее, Я ничего не понял.

Comment: А так вообще Опера тут причём?

Comment: Это общий пример, возьмите необходимое.

Comment: Мне нужно только для мозиллы, Я и так и сяк пробовал, ну ничего не выходит. Может Вы ошиблись? Ставлю текст в строке где мозилла а выходит тот текст который Я поставил для оперы.

Comment: Двойные кавычки забыл, исправил в коде.

Comment: Всё тоже самое: Ставлю текст в строке где мозилла, а выходит тот текст который Я поставил для оперы.
Напишите пожалуйста только для мозиллы.

Comment: Если и сейчас все будет непонятно, запутанно и не заработает - я начну материться) Только что все это проверил - все работает.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте User-Agent и в зависимости от них, ставьте нужную кнопку.

**Добавлено:**

navigator.appCodeName - Кодовое название браузера

navigator.appName - Название браузера

navigator.appVersion - полная информация о версии браузера.

Comment: А как это сделать через JS?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(/firefox/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    //перед нами огнелис. можно выбрать ссылку по id и поменять ее title
}
```

Полагаться на userAgent, конечно же, ненадежно (легко подменить), но пусть это останется на совести пользователя.
А вот вам букмарклет для разбора свойств объекта. Поможет в будущем, и не только с navigator. =)

```
javascript:var str='';for(i in navigator)str+=i+': '+navigator[i]+'\n';alert(str);void(0);
```

Comment: И как потом уже через HTML на этот именно скрипт ссылаться?

Comment: Ну даже и не знаю, [что в этом случае посоветовать][1].

[1]: http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/start